# Inheritance of WPF-Controls doesn´t work

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, inheritance, plugins

I´m implementing a plugin-based software and want to allow the plugin developer to specify a GUI element for display of data and settings. But I´m not able to subclass the baseclass of the control (type can not be found in the assembly). This is what I´ve done:

1.) Implemented in the "widgetbase"-project the base class (code only, no XAML):

```
namespace widgetbase
{
    public class WidgetControl : Control
    {
    }
}
```

2.) Built the project and included a reference to it in "mywidget"-project.

3.) I´ve created a new custom WPF control and changed the implementation that it will derive from my base:

```
<wc:WidgetControl x:Class="mywidget.MyWidgetControl" 
                  xmlns:wc="clr-namespace:widgetbase"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid Margin="20" Background="Blue">
            <TextBlock Text="Test" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</wc:WidgetControl>
```

Code-behind:

```
namespace mywidget
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MyWidgetControl : WidgetControl
    {
        public MyWidgetControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

4.) I´ve tried to build the project, but the type "WidgetControl" can not be found in "widgetbase". I don´t get it, I´ve declared the type public, included the reference to the base and adjusted both - codebehind and XAML. In the code-behind everything is fine, the type "WidgetControl" can be resolved.

Why can´t the type be found in XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xmlns:wc="clr-namespace:widgetbase"
```

Is not a full declaration. If you are going into a different assembly (certainly sounds like you are since you needed a reference), you have to note that in the XMLNS:

```
xmlns:wc="clr-namespace:widgetbase;assembly=WidgetCommon"
```

Also consider deriving from `UserControl`, `Control` is a little more abstract. That, and namespaces should be PascalCase :)

Comment: both projects are in the same solution. The declaration was a suggestion by Visual Studio. I changed it now to  xmlns:wc="clr-namespace:widgetbase;assembly=widgetbase.dll" but it does not solve the problem

Comment: The solution doesn't matter, if its different projects, you have to use the assembly name. Remove the DLL extension, you just need the *name*